# How to do express routing with the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I read the express guide to try to understand how to to this but if I have my website and in the url the form is [site url]/home or [site url]/profile how do I make it so the url actually shows like that. Right now its [site url]/pathtohome.html instead. I'm using an express server.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))
})
```

Comment: In your code, you are sending back an html once you receive a `GET` from `/`. What exactly are you trying to send back ?

Comment: @AbinThaha Thats just the code starting the express server. What I want is so when you edit the url to [sitename]/profile I can route them to that respective page, but instead of showing [sitename]/public/html/profile.html I just want it to say [sitename]/profile. How can I do that?